# Spring Security Url Pattern is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

This is my security-context.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user authorities="admin" name="logan"
                    password="user" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="denyAll" />
        <security:form-login />
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

I dont know why I am still able to access all the things after /admin ,like /admin/home is redirecting me to the dashboard instead of redirecting me to the login page ,how does this work ?? I am fairly new to spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you include the file in `web.xml` like:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

You could also try adding `/*` in url pattern:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's still a guess, but I think "just" adding an "asterix" `*` to filter-mapping, could fix the issue:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

?

Cewl, it also means you did everything else correct...
on "how" & "why" (it is something web.xml/servlet spec specific ...assuming 3.0):

- [The servlet spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf)
- ...and [some web.xml doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/web_xml.html#wp1039330)